# WCF to receive large strings, get exception

Tags: wcf, web-services

I went through all the posts about this, nothing helped, so I posted this because I'm pulling my hair out.

I have a WCF web-service that has a method that receives a string, a long string. It works with a string of 2,390,158 characters (tried it) but won't work with a string of about 5,440,519 characters. (I'm using VS 2010)

I have this error:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response http:// localhost : 58014/ WSWebService.asmx. The reason may be that the connection endpoint service does not use the HTTP protocol. This may also be due to a HTTP request context has been ignored by the server (possibly due to the discontinuation of service).

I put all parameters I could at int.MaxValue (2,147,483,647) but it still won't work. Any help/suggestion is gladly appreciated.

I removed the "timeout" parts but it makes no difference :

```
closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
```

Here's the binding in my app.config:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSWebServiceSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="20971520"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

My config server side is :

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSWebServiceSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="20971520"
       messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
       maxBufferSize="20971520" maxBufferPoolSize="20971520"
       useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

So yes, same configuration. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sharing this config across both client and server?

Comment: Try upping your maxReceivedMessageSize? I think you'll need to add MaxBufferSize too at the same value.

Comment: You need to use the same settings on both Client and Server as said by @PrestonGuillot

Comment: Do you have a definition for endpoint that explicitly uses your defined binding?  If you don't, then .NET will use (via default endpoints and bindings) the default values for the `basicHttpBinding`.

Comment: The service appears to be an ASMX service. It doesn't care about the `<serviceModel>` element.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Good catch.  I didn't even see that.

Comment: @JohnSaunders So what are my options, how can I make it work?

Comment: Maybe time to upgrade to WCF. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service was ASMX based, redone it pure WCF and now it works.